# How to update CHANGELOG in git automatically by MR

Tags: git, gitlab

We work with git connected to Jira. I would like the CHANGELOG.md file to be updated automatically every time I approve a merge request. Is there an easy option?

Comment: What information do you want to write in it?

Answer (score 0):

to Create changelogs using the GitLab API, check this [Link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#generate-changelog-data) out, please.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a jira automation rule which is triggered by a Github webhook if a release is published. The rule will set the Jira Relase with the same name as the git tag to "Released" and send all the assigned tickets as a release note back to github via the github rest api.

Maybe you can do something similar.